# Express js middleware is not working as expected. It is showing too many redirections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express js middleware is not working as expected. It is showing too many redirections.
When i remove the token or logout it shows in the browser that too many  redirections

**Middleware**

```
const isAuthenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, "thisisjwtsecret", async (err, token_decode) => {
      if (!err) {
        const u_id = token_decode._id;
        const userData = await User.findOne({ _id: u_id });
        req.user = userData;
        req.isAuth = true;
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect("/user/login");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/user/login");
    }
};
```

**Route.js**

```
// Auth Controller
const AuthController = require("../../controllers/auth/AuthController");
const { isAuthenticate } = require("../../middlewares/isAutheticated");

router.get("/user/login", isAuthenticate, AuthController.login);
router.post("/user/login", AuthController.checkLogin);
router.get("/user/register", isAuthenticate, AuthController.createUser);
router.post("/user/register", isAuthenticate, AuthController.storeUser);
module.exports = router;
```

**LOgin function**

```
// Showing Login Page to User
const login = (req, res) => {
  return res.render("auth/login");
};
```

When i remove the token or logout it shows in the browser that too many  redirections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've shown revised code for `isAuthenticate()`, the redirect loop is caused by the redirects in that code.  Here's what happens:

Some route you have (any route) that uses `isAuthenticate` as middleware for the route detects that the user is not logged in.  It then redirects to `/user/login`.  That's fine up to that point.  Then, the browser issues a new request for `/user/login` and that takes you to this route definition:

```
router.get("/user/login", isAuthenticate, AuthController.login);
```

But, that route definition again runs the `isAuthenticate()` middleware which redirects to `/user/login` and thus you have an infinite redirect loop.

Probably you just need to remove the `isAuthenticate()` check from this route.  If the user is already going to the `/user/login` page, you don't need to check their authentication or redirect them.  If you have a reason to want to know if they are authenticated or not, then you need a separate version that ONLY does the auth check and does not redirect and you can use that in the `/user/login` route definition.

---

**Original answer before code was shown that did res.redirect().**

So, this middleware you show sets `req.isAuth` to `true` or `false` and then calls `next()` to continue routing.  All three code paths through that middleware just set `req.isAuth` and then call `next()`.  Nowhere in this middleware does it do any redirect.  So, if the core problem is too many redirections, that issue must be caused somewhere else by some other route/middleware that actually does a redirect, probably when it sees that `req.isAuth` is `false` since you said that the problem occurs when logged out or when the token is missing.

When redirecting, you have to make absolutely sure that when you redirect to a URL, there is ZERO chance (no code path of any kind) that the route handler for that URL will also redirect to that URL.  That's how you get into a redirect loop.

Looking at the other routes you show, if the too many redirects issue is when redirecting to `/user/login`, then it seems likely the problem is in the `authController.login()` handler from this route:

```
router.get("/user/login", isAuthenticate, AuthController.login);
```

If the code for that route checks `req.isAuth` and redirects in any circumstances, then that would be an endless redirect loop.

If you need further advice, please provide the following information:

1. Which exact redirect URL is causing the problem of too many redirects?  Is is `/user/login`?
2. Show us the code for the route that does that redirect because that's apparently where the fault is.

---

Comment: I have updated the code and added login function @jfriend00

Comment: @SwapnilMane - OK, now that you've updated the middleware code and accepted this answer, I guess you figured out where your redirect loop was being caused?

Comment: Actually sir... Your answer was helpful and i  removed unwanted code that's why I accepted but it is still in redirected loop...i

Comment: @SwapnilMane - OK, I've added some new explanation to the start of my answer.

Comment: Yes sir...Great...Thanks My problem got solved @jfriend00. Bt now i want to redirect user to the dashboard if user is already logged in...How can I do this ??

Comment: Here's the link to that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619269/i-want-to-redirect-to-dashboard-if-user-is-already-logged-in-when-he-try-to-acce