# I want to redirect to dashboard if user is already logged in when he try to access login route in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, middleware

I want to redirect to dashboard if user is already logged in when he try to access login route in express js

**Middleware**

```
const isAuthenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, "thisisjwtsecret", async (err, token_decode) => {
      if (!err) {
        const u_id = token_decode._id;
        const userData = await User.findOne({ _id: u_id });
        req.user = userData;
        req.isAuth = true;
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect("/user/login");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/user/login");
    }
};
```

**Route.js**

```
// Auth Controller
const AuthController = require("../../controllers/auth/AuthController");
const { isAuthenticate } = require("../../middlewares/isAutheticated");

router.get("/user/login", isAuthenticate, AuthController.login);
router.post("/user/login", AuthController.checkLogin);
router.get("/user/register", isAuthenticate, AuthController.createUser);
router.post("/user/register", isAuthenticate, AuthController.storeUser);
module.exports = router;
```

**LOgin function**

```
// Showing Login Page to User
const login = (req, res) => {
  return res.render("auth/login");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break out the functionality from your existing `isAuthenticate()` function so it just returns a result and then use that to do something like this:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const verify = promisify(jwt.verify);

// resolves if jwt cookie verifies and user found
// rejects if jwt cookie is missing or doesn't verify or user not found
async function isLoggedIn(req) {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if (!token) throw new Error("no jwt cookie");
    const token_decode = await verify(token, "thisisjwtsecret");
    let user = await User.findOne({ _id: token_decode._id });
    if (!user) throw new Error("user not found");
    return;
}

// Showing Login Page to User
// Or redirect to /dashboard if already logged in
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await isLoggedIn(req);
        // already logged in, redirect to dashboard
        // you MUST make sure that /dashboard does not redirect to /user/login itself
        // when isLoggedIn resolves to avoid circular redirects
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    } catch (e) {
        // not logged in, render the login page
        res.render("auth/login");
    }
};
```

The `isLoggedIn(req)` function resolves if the token validates and the user is found in the database.  Otherwise, it rejects.  You can then use that in other routes to decide whether you want to redirect or not.

Comment: It worked. But is it okay to fetch the data from the database when user goes to another pages. Co i have already used ```isAuthenticate``` middleware for every route. and It fetches the data when user navigates.

Comment: @SwapnilMane - That is up to you.  If you trust the login test to ONLY verify the jwt token in the cookie, then you can leave out the database check.

Comment: But sir is there a way where I can write a function which help me to  access user data and and it will hit the database only once and the data will be usable in every function without calling. A middleware again and again...??

Comment: @SwapnilMane - See [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).  You can then lookup stuff for a particular user once when they login in, store it in the server-side session and then use that on all future requests for that user.   Or, you can just rely on the  jwt token too, but it isn't as flexible as express-session because you don't typically put lots of other data in the token. You don't show the overall context of your code here or explain why you're already using a token so it's hard for us to participate in overall design discussions.